# unconfirmed transaction, need help^

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

Someone could help me to get my transaction confirmed?
https://blockchain.info/tx/b4d0654d76c4a324da92643270b174c0439b59c42fe5f1d6d570b768f9febf89

Regards,

Comment: No one can help me? :( 15 hrs waiting

Answer (score 0):

Try using a bitcoin accelerator:
https://www.viabtc.com/tools/txaccelerator/

Comment: Yeah right, use accelerator, and as much as possible do not choose the lowest fee to pay the miner. It will take your bitcoin transaction to get confirmed.